# Laravel 4.2 is_online article

Tags: php, laravel-4

I'm confronted to a little problem, i try to add a method to show only online article, but i want to know how do implement this method.
In my DB i have a row is_online (Int) for  0=> offline, 1=>online, how do implement that for my view.

in my models with

```
public function isonline(){}
```

or in my PostController in my request of post find.

And after need to add in my admin panel a check box in Post create to change the status off article (online or offline-draft).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `Eloquent` scope in your code by creating `online` scope in your model.

```
public function scopeOnline($query)
{
    return $query->where('is_online', 1);
}
```

Draft posts

```
public function scopeDrafts($query)
{
    return $query->where('is_online', 0);
}
```

Then in your code you can simply use it like this.

```
$onlinePosts = Post::online()->get();

$draftPosts = Post::drafts()->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to find all records who have flag `is_online = 1`.

You can write one method in your `PostController` like

```
Public function getOnlineRecords{

    $records = YourModel::where('is_online','=',1)->get();
    return View::make('your_view_path',['records'=>$records]);
}
```

In your View file, you need to write:-

```
 {{ Form::checkbox('your_field_name', 'value', true) }}
```

If you want to default the value as checked, pass `true` as the `third argument`.